# date picker which displays date like thursday, Febraury 9, 2012

Tags: php, javascript

Can any one please suggest me a datepicker which displays date like thursday, Febraury 9, 2012 after user selects date from date picker.And is it possible to place the next and previous functionalities.

I am using Javascript on client side. PHP on server side.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's UI [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and its dateFormat parameter.

```
$( "input" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, MM dd, yy' });
```

This page has a list of possible formats.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to accomplish this with the [jQuery UI Datapicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats). It has extremely flexible date formatting capabilities.